# Function with equal limits that is defined but not continous

Tags: calculus

Create a function, $f(x)$, and pick a point $c$ such that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ from the right and the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ from the left are equal, the function is defined at the point $c$ but the function is not continuous at $c$. Show the values of the limits and explain why the function is not continuous.

I can explain it intuitively, but I am struggling with a mathematical explanation.

Comment: Do you know what a removable discontinuity is?  Also, do you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity?  Both of these concepts will come in handy when solving this problem.

Comment: I didn't think a removable discontinuity would work since it needs to be defined at point c

Comment: Here is a picture of a removable discontinuity: http://www.mathwords.com/r/r_assets/r88.gif

Comment: In that picture, the function is defined at all points, and at the removable discontinuity, the limits from the left and right are equal, but the function is discontinuous at that point.  You can construct a function similar to this and prove using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity that it is discontinuous at that point.

Comment: Would that example still be defined at that point? I was using (x2 - 1)/(x - 1), equal limits and discontinuous, but it is undefined when x=1. I guess I'm just confused on how to have a point c that is both defined and not continuous. Or maybe a better way to say it is that I'm confused on how to describe it

Comment: Did you see the answer that was posted?  That answer is basically this: Consider the constant function $f(x) = 0$.  Now, just change this function at one point, say, $x = 0$.  Make $f(0) = 1$.  Then our function is $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x = 0  \end{cases}$.  Try sketching this function, and you'll see that it is defined everywhere, and at $x = 0$ the limits from the left and right are equal, but it is not continuous at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} f(x)$ but $f(0) = 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: I was using (x2 - 1)/(x - 1), equal limits and discontinuous, but it is undefined when x=1. I guess I'm just confused on how to have a point c that is both defined and not continuous. Or maybe a better way to say it is that I'm confused on how to describe it

Comment: As in your construction, you can define the image of $x = 1$ at any value not equal to 2. It also works.